# Pandas - Interate over row and compare previous values -faster

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to get my results faster (13 minutes for 800 rows). I asked a similar question here: [pandas - iterate over rows and calculate - faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294105/pandas-iterate-over-rows-and-calculate-faster/59295803#59295803) - but I not able to use the good solutions for my variation. The difference is that if the overlap of previous values in 'col2' is more than 'n=3', the value of 'col1' in the row is set to '0' and affect the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [20, 23, 40, 41, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 50, 52, 55, 56, 69, 70],
    'col2': [39, 32, 42, 50, 63, 67, 64, 68, 68, 74, 59, 75, 58, 71, 66]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


df["overlap_count"] = ""  #create new column
n = 3 #if x >= n, then value = 0

for row in range(len(df)):
        x = (df["col2"].loc[0:row-1] > (df["col1"].loc[row])).sum()
        df["overlap_count"].loc[row] = x

        if x >= n:                 
            df["col2"].loc[row] = 0
            df["overlap_count"].loc[row] = 'x'
df
```

I obtain following result: replacing values in col1 if they are greater than 'n' and the column overlap_count

```
   col1 col2 overlap_count
0   20  39  0
1   23  32  1
2   40  42  0
3   41  50  1
4   46  63  1
5   47  67  2
6   48  0   x
7   49  0   x
8   50  68  2
9   50  0   x
10  52  0   x
11  55  0   x
12  56  0   x
13  69  71  0
14  70  66  1
```

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Can you please show as the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `numba` for improve performance, only is necessary working with numeric values, so instead `x` is added `-1` and new column is filled by `0` instead empty string:

```
df["overlap_count"] = 0  #create new column
n = 3 #if x >= n, then value = 0

a = df[['col1','col2','overlap_count']].values

from numba import njit

@njit
def custom_sum(arr, n):
    for row in range(arr.shape[0]):
        x = (arr[0:row, 1] > arr[row, 0]).sum()
        arr[row, 2] = x
        if x >= n:
            arr[row, 1] = 0
            arr[row, 2] = -1
    return arr
```

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(custom_sum(a, n), columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
    col1  col2  overlap_count
0     20    39              0
1     23    32              1
2     40    42              0
3     41    50              1
4     46    63              1
5     47    67              2
6     48     0             -1
7     49     0             -1
8     50    68              2
9     50     0             -1
10    52     0             -1
11    55     0             -1
12    56     0             -1
13    69    71              0
14    70    66              1
```

**Performance**:

```
d = {'col1': [20, 23, 40, 41, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 50, 52, 55, 56, 69, 70],
    'col2': [39, 32, 42, 50, 63, 67, 64, 68, 68, 74, 59, 75, 58, 71, 66]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#4500rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 300, ignore_index=True)

print (df)
In [115]: %%timeit
     ...: pd.DataFrame(custom_sum(a, n), columns=df.columns)
     ...: 
8.11 ms ± 224 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [116]: %%timeit 
     ...: for row in range(len(df)):
     ...:         x = (df["col2"].loc[0:row-1] > (df["col1"].loc[row])).sum()
     ...:         df["overlap_count"].loc[row] = x
     ...: 
     ...:         if x >= n:                 
     ...:             df["col2"].loc[row] = 0
     ...:             df["overlap_count"].loc[row] = 'x'
     ...:             
     ...:             
7.84 s ± 442 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: @jezarel, may you can answer this extension... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078906/numba-how-i-can-count-occurrences-in-an-numba-loop

Answer (score 0):

create a function and then just apply the function as shown below:

df['overlap_count'] = [fn(i) for i in df['overlap_count']]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, maybe it will be faster.

```
df['overlap_count'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda g: len((g >= g.name).index))
```

Comment: sorry, the results are no like i expect it. Thank you!

Comment: Do you expect the amount of unique values >= x, or the number of rows? 
In case of unique replace `g >= g.name` by `g.drop_duplicates() >= g.name`

Comment: if you look at index 8, where col1 = 50 and the previous values of col2 are 39,32... 63,67,0.0. the code looks how many values are >= than 50. the result is 2 (63,67). if the result would be > n=3, than index 8, col2 value would change from 68 to 0

Comment: I don't really get the logic. Why 68? do you want to refill overlap_count, or do something else?